# what is convert.Toint16(c1.selectscalar(str)==0)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This my my code:

```
    string str_check;
    str_check = "select count(*) from tbl_AdminLogin 
                 where AdminId='" + txt_admin.Text + "' and Password='" 
                 + txt_pswd.Text + "'";
    if (Convert.ToInt16(c1.selectScalar(str_check)) == 0)
    {
        lbl_errmsg.Text = "Invalid Admin";
    }
    else
    {
        Session.Add("adminid", txt_admin.Text);
        Response.Redirect("AdminHome.aspx");
    }
    ///THIS IS THE WHOLE PROJECT CS//
```

What does this line do? :

```
 if(Convert.ToInt16(c1.selectScalar(str_check)) == 0)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `c1`?

Comment: You have the code, you know what c1 is  and what selectScalar returns, we could only guess. Could you show something more to us?

Comment: -1 Neither `c1`nor `selectScalar` are part of the .NET framework and you haven't provided what type `c1` is and what `selectScalar` does, so how should we know it?

Answer (score 1):

A Scalar call returns a single, discreet value.  Your `selectScalar` call is executing the passed (susceptible to SQL Injection, I might add) SQL, and returning the value - in this case the count of rows returned.  Given that the return value from this call is `object` it needs to be converted to be tested, in this case `ToInt16`.

In short, the code is seeing if the count of rows is zero, thereby implying that the username and password do not match.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `Convert.ToInt16` to convert the return value of `c1.selectScalar(str_check)` to an integer so you can compare it to `0`

If you have a look at the documentation for [ToInt16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint16.aspx) you see that there are a lot of overloads that try to convert all kinds of types to an int16.

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToInt16 will convert the object to integer.

I feel you should consider comparing the string rather than increasing a step to convert it to integer.